# How to set rounded profile picture image(from url string) to UIBarButton item in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

Hi I'm working on an iOS Swift project in which I want to show users profile picture in the navigation bar as rounded. I tried lot of sample code, but it is not making rounded curve. Please help me.

I have tried these codes,

```
var image = UIImage()
if let userImage = UserProfile.image {
   let imageUrl = self.dmcCommon.convertStringToImageURL(url: userImage)
   let data = (try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl as URL))!
   image = UIImage(data: data)!
} else {
   image = UIImage(named: "Me")!
}

let v = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
v.image = image
v.layer.masksToBounds = true
v.layer.cornerRadius = 20

let rightBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: v)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBtn
```

And the result is like this,
[image]
Here the image is not getting round also it taking full width not as I gave.

Later I tried another solution, which is,

```
let button = UIButton()
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
var image = UIImage()
if let userImage = UserProfile.image {
   let imageUrl = self.dmcCommon.convertStringToImageURL(url: userImage)
   let data = (try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl as URL))!
   image = UIImage(data: data)!
} else {
   image = UIImage(named: "Me")!
}
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(button.frame.size, false, image.scale)
let rect  = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:button.frame.size.width, height:button.frame.size.height)
UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: rect.width/2).addClip()
image.draw(in: rect)
let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.navToMe), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
let color = UIColor(patternImage: newImage)
button.backgroundColor = color
button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem()
barButton.customView = button
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [notificationButton, barButton]
```

And the result is,
[image]

In second solution it working but the image is redrawing like mirroring to down. Please help me how to place rounded profile picture in UIBarButtonItems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used the following approch,

```
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
button.layer.cornerRadius = 15
button.clipsToBounds = true
button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string : "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png")!)

if let imageData = imageData , let image =  UIImage(data: imageData)?.resizeImage(to: button.frame.size) {
    button.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
}
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

To resize the image

```
extension UIImage {
    func resizeImage(to size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
       return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { _ in
           draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
    }
}}
```

[image]

In the above example, I've used `Data(contentsOf: URL)` to load image from the internet, but it is better to fetch the image asynchronously. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    let customView = UIView(frame: frame)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "turtle"))
    imageView.frame = frame
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.height * 0.5
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    customView.addSubview(imageView)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [
        UIBarButtonItem(systemItem: .action), UIBarButtonItem(customView: customView)
    ]
```

[image]

Instead of UIImage(name:) use your UIImage(data:) constructor

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a custom button or an image view. And do not use corner rounding. Just draw the target image into the desired size with clipping to a circle and use that as the bar button item’s `image`.

Comment: Hi@matt, can you just provide any example for this?

Comment: @matt What's the reason for not to use corner rounding?